# Why cant I route to localhost /login?

Tags: python, routes, localhost

Im new to python and trying to setup a practice webapp.

```
from flask import Blueprint

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

@views.route('/')
def home():
    return "<h1>Test</h1>"
```

When i run this the result comes out fine [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bscDI.png)

127.0.0.1:8080/login (anything i put after "/" page doesnt load.)

Ex: when i run this

```
from flask import Blueprint

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)


@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    return "<h1>Login</h1>"
```

i get [404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFwgN.png)

please advise.

Comment: Could not reproduce. Maybe you forgot to register that second blueprint?

Comment: not sure but i forgot to add anything i put after the "/" page doesnt load

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Blueprint, Flask

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

@views.route('/')
def home():
    return "<h1>Test</h1>"

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    return "<h1>Login</h1>"

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

I think this is what you're trying to do.  You neglected to "register" your blueprints to the app.  Default port is 5000 I believe

Comment: well i have that in my __init__ file

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'abcd'

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

    return app
```